# Create PDF report in ASP C# by using database

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

i'm trying to create a PDF by using database in ASP C#. PDF will include just titles and contents so what do i have to use to do such a thing and can you provide me a some examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) which is an open source pdf library.

You can find a documentation format [here](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/).

Book reference : [iText in Action](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/)

[Generate PDF using iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp) can be a good startup on how to use iTextSharp to generate PDF using asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for html -> pdf conversion. You can use a free command line utility [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) for it.

If you want something more complex like prepare multiple templates or store history of pdf outputs. Look at free reporting server [jsreport](http://jsreport.net). ( I am the author)